# Why HangFire same name with recurring jobs not working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jobs, hangfire

I had scheduled jobs with same name and different parameter but it is not added in hangfire server and only last job is added in server any thing I missed ? my code is below

```
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
            () => Console.WriteLine("HelloNew jobCreated, "),
            Cron.Minutely);
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
            () => Console.WriteLine("HelloNew jobCreated 12, "),
            Cron.Minutely);
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
           () => Console.WriteLine("HelloNew jobCreated 2, "),
           Cron.Minutely);
```

Only last job is added in server `Console.WriteLine("HelloNew jobCreated 2, ");`

Answer (score 7):

You need to [read the docs](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html).

> Each recurring job has its own unique identifier. In the previous examples it was generated implicitly, using the type and method names of the given call expression (resulting in "Console.Write" as the identifier). The RecurringJob class contains overloads that take an explicitly defined job identifier. So that you can refer to the job later.

Since the type and method name is the same each time, the result is they have the same ID, and are therefore the same job, and since the method is called AddOr**Update** it's overwriting each time.

To not overwrite, assign explicit unique identifiers for each recurring job.

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
        "Job1",
        () => Console.WriteLine("HelloNew jobCreated, "),
        Cron.Minutely);
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
        "Job2",
        () => Console.WriteLine("HelloNew jobCreated 12, "),
        Cron.Minutely);
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
       "Job3",
       () => Console.WriteLine("HelloNew jobCreated 2, "),
       Cron.Minutely);
```

Comment: Thanks @mason for help